# Access remote jQuery file

Tags: jquery, html, installation

I am building a website (to be accessed by only 3 members). I need to install jQuery in that website. Since, it is a website with very limited members, I decided to have the jQuery file in the C drive of every PC and decided to link to it instead so that the page load time is decreased. But, the link is not working.
The following is my code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="file:///C:/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("body").html("Replaced text");
});
</script>
<body>

Replace this text
</body>
```

Is it not possible to fetch the remote jQuery file?

Comment: The above code works for me, are you sure you don't have a typing error in the actual file?

Comment: @AshutoshGojiya, the above code must have worked for you when you had not uploaded the file into the server and must have accessed it remotely

Comment: remember that web is executing in your server a don't has access to open files in the client computer, in the console i got this error Not allowed to load local resource, it has to be inside the server folder or get it by http

Comment: @devaldcool, yes I have used php in my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is no such way by which you can access a user's local file. This will be  a huge security exception. There is only one way by which you can access a user's file, i.e. when the user uploads the files voluntarily.

---

Now, offering you a solution, if you have only 3-4 members **and they are not variable**, then you must try using a local server. *Why access the web pages online when you can access them offline?*

Using a local server may save you bandwith as well as pages will load immensely fast. And then **YES** you can store the jquery file in your project folder which is in the local machine.

---

For starters, [WAMP SERVER](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) and [XAMPP SERVER](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/) can prove to be a boon. They are included with mysql, php and administrating features. This must be exactly what you are looking for.

---

Furthur comments : If the users are connected with LAN (which I guess in your case), you can install WAMP or XAMPP in only one machine and access it using the I.P. address of the server machine. For eg -> `192.168.1.2/YOUR_APP/` and access it in the server machine as `localhost/YOUR_APP`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will definitely download WAMP and XAMPP

Comment: @h2O, NO! DO NOT DOWNLOAD BOTH. This will lead mysql being downloaded twice and create a serious trouble

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="file:///C:/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').html('Replaced text');
});
</script>
<body>

Replace this text
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't think you can access the file this way

`<script src="file:///C:/jquery.min.js"></script>`

try to get from other web resource

`<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>` 
or as

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`

and another thing, in your code at line 7 and 8 why are there two `});` ending brackets.

Comment: I know that I can access the jQuery file using the normal way, but I WANT TO ACCESS it REMOTELY. Please read the question properly

Comment: Ok got your point, you can access file with relative path not with absolute path.