# How can I send a file/script from client to server using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I have a file in my client folder that contains some PhP scripts to be sent to the server. The file name is known and we have no user in client side to browse the disk and then upload the file (I saw some codes in Internet showing how to upload a file from disk to server). I need to know how can I give the file name in jquery and send the file from the disk to the server and store it somewhere in the server.

I understand it is associated with some security risks, but this is only for an experiment that is hard to explain.

**Note:** I don't need the code that needs user to "Choose File" and then hit the Upload button.

**Further Note:** Consider a web-based application running entirely in client side (local web server) with 5 sub-tasks. At runtime, we decide to run 2 out of 5 tasks inside the local web server at client side and the rest to upload to server for execution. Then how should this script go from client to sever. It does not need to be file.php, but any data type that can hold PHP code is fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "we have no user in client side..." part?

Comment: [Y u no google](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Comment: @cjs1978, I mean we don't want user to do the manual task. The code itself need to send the file to server at runtime. Hope it is clear enough.

Comment: hard to make any sense out of what you are asking. Please explain in more concise steps

Comment: That's not possible without running some sort of server on the client itself as far as I can tell. How should the upload be invoked? jQuery (or any javascript) does not do anything just by itself, but maybe if it was a NodeJS server or similar.

Comment: I have read your question like three times now, but I still don't get what you are trying to do. Are you trying to copy one file from your client's server to your own server at specific times?

Comment: further note provided.

Comment: Do you want to move the PHP files themselves from client to server? Sorry, I have a hard time grasping this.

Comment: This looks like a [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you **really** want to do?

Comment: Why do you need a client side if there is no user there to see it? Why not run server side scripts with a cron job? Servers (even local) can share files with another server just fine.

Comment: There is a user, but we don't want user to get engaged in such distractive activities.

Comment: It seems to me that there's something "architecturally" wrong with the setup - why do you want to move the PHP scripts back and forth; why not just run them on the server when needed by calling i.e. a URL on the server with some parameters?

Comment: I have already done what you explained and thus claimed that when running already-stored code in the server side, there would not be any code transfer traffic from client to server. However, a non-expert has created a dilemma for me to prove him that my claim is true via real experiment. So I should do something wrong and show him what I did is right. So confusing and frustrating.

Comment: You should guide him (the non-expert) to this page then :-) I'm pretty sure plenty of people here will confirm that you are right in asserting that there's no need to move the PHP-code itself to a server in order to execute it. As an example: If you need to use an API of some sort (on a server), you just call it. You don't start out by uploading the code that forms the API to the server each time. (I don't know about your exact project, so this might not be totally analogous, but anyway.)

Comment: :) I afraid I cannot do invite him to here.

Answer (score 0):

With just the browser, you can't read a file from the client's disk even if you know the file's name and location. If it was possible, everybody would be able to copy the files from each other's disks.

You can create a tiny application that runs on the client machine, outside of the browser. It could periodically poll the server to see if an upload is requested. If so, it can read the requested files and post them to your service.

Answer (score 0):

To quote my own answer from [Access remote jQuery file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158631/access-remote-jquery-file/26239645#26239645), `there is no such way by which you can access a user's local file. This will be a huge security exception. There is only one way by which you can access a user's file, i.e. when the user uploads the files voluntarily.`

---

Now, offering you a solution, if you have only 3-4 members and they are not variable, then you must try using a local server. Why access the web pages online when you can access them offline?

---

Using a local server may save you bandwith as well as pages will load immensely fast. And then YES you can store the file in your project folder which is in the local machine.

---

For starters, [WAMP SERVER](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) and [XAMPP SERVER](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/) can prove to be a boon. They are included with mysql, php and administrating features. This must be exactly what you are looking for.